# Displaying FrameTicks Only on Specified Axes

Tags: graphics, ticks

I am trying to make a plot with `FrameTicks` and I would like to have them displayed only on the left and bottom axes. However, the way I wrote the definition, it displays the frameticks everywhere. Below is the snippet of my code.

```
g1 = Graphics[{Gray, Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {10, 1}]}];
g2 = Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 1}]}];

ccbarexpmasses = {{1, 3.0687}, {2, 3.5259}, {3, 3.6740},
   {4, 4.0390}, {5, 4.4214}, {6, 3.773}, {7, 4.1915}}

(* {{1, 3.0687}, {2, 3.5259}, {3, 3.674}, {4, 4.039},
  {5, 4.4214}, {6, 3.773}, {7, 4.1915}} *)

ccbartheorymasses = {{1, 3.0644101}, {2, 3.5220701}, {3, 
   3.663467}, {4, 4.070219}, {5, 4.4096141}, {6, 3.801675},
   {7, 4.1639293}}

(* {{1, 3.06441}, {2, 3.52207}, {3, 3.66347}, {4, 4.07022},
  {5, 4.40961}, {6, 3.80168}, {7, 4.16393}} *)

CCbarcomparison = 
 ListPlot[{ccbarexpmasses, ccbartheorymasses}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria Math", 14, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"", "E (GeV)"}, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 4.0, 
     4.2, 4.4}}, PlotMarkers -> {{g1, 40}, {g2, 40}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{1, "1S"}, {2, "1P"}, {3, "2S"}, {4, "3S"}, {5, 
      "4S"}, {6, "1D"}, {7, "2D"}, {8, "ff"}}, {3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8,
      4.0, 4.2, 4.4}}]
```

and the output. [image: ccbar]
I tried to add the `None` option as

```
FrameTicks -> {{{1, "1S"}, {2, "1P"}, {3, "2S"}, {4, "3S"},
   {5, "4S"}, {6, "1D"}, {7, "2D"}, None},
   {3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 4.4}, None}
```

but that removes the labeling of the $x$ tickmarks and displays them as numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `FrameTicks -> {{{3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 4.4}, 
    None}, {{{1, "1S"}, {2, "1P"}, {3, "2S"}, {4, "3S"}, {5, 
      "4S"}, {6, "1D"}, {7, "2D"}, {8, "ff"}}, None}}]`

Comment: `FrameTicks` syntax is {{*left*, *right*}, {*bottom*, *top*}}, so try `FrameTicks -> {
  {{3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8,  4.0, 4.2, 4.4}, None}, {{{1, "1S"}, {2, "1P"}, {3, "2S"}, {4, "3S"}, {5,  "4S"}, {6, "1D"}, {7, "2D"}}, None}
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FrameTicks -> {{{3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 4.4}, 
None}, {{{1, "1S"}, {2, "1P"}, {3, "2S"}, {4, "3S"}, {5, "4S"}, {6,
  "1D"}, {7, "2D"}, {8, "ff"}}, None}}
```